# Show current database record

Tags: php, mysql

For the 'wachtwoord' input field, the value is the current database record. But how can I show the current record for the 'Jaar' select field? It's currently showing one, but it has to be two.. Anyone know how to solve this?

```
<label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $t['gids_password'] ?>"/>

    <br/>

    <label for="jaar">Jaar</label>
    <select name="jaar" id="jaar">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to compare the result from the database with the value of the options. If it matches, you need to `echo 'selected';` Like so:

```
    <option value="1" <?php if($t['gids_jaar']==1){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($t['gids_jaar']==2){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if($t['gids_jaar']==3){ echo 'selected'; } ?> >3</option>
```

**NOTE:**

`$t['gids_jaar']` would be the value of the database. Dont forget to put space between the closing php tag and the end of the option open tag. So this part has to have a space:

```
 ?> >3</option>
```

there has to be a space between the `?>` and `>`

The answer of [Daan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431805/show-current-database-record/29431851#29431851) works as well but I just wanted to add some additional information.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Although, when I choose for example 3 now and i press submit and refresh the page. It won't submit. Other input fields are working tho

Comment: @user3071261 I assume this whole script is an attempt to edit values in the database. You would have to ask another question with the `UPDATE` query in it and the post/get values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `selected` to one of your option tags, most easy is with a ternary operator:

```
<option value="1" <?php echo ($t['myvalfromdb'] == 1) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo ($t['myvalfromdb'] == 2) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >1</option>
<option value="3" <?php echo ($t['myvalfromdb'] == 3) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >1</option>
```